# Pytest bdd, the features aren't recognized anymore

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, language-features, pytest-bdd

I have a strange case. I can't run my pytest anymore because he doesn't found the features (who are there btw).

Here is the error message and the proof that the files are there .

Thx
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the command you used to run pytest as well as the working directory

Comment: I run python -m pytest and the working directory is the one on the screen (i.e ../steps_def)

Answer (score 0):

I run python -m pytest and the working directory is the one on the screen (i.e ../steps_def)